# Enlarge or shrink the codomain will not change the continuity of a function?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

Suppose we have a function $f$ from $X$ to $Y$, it seems to me that 'Enlarge and shrink the codomain will not change the continuity of a function'

Since we have $fX \subset Y$

First case $Y=fX$, if I enlarge it, for example to $Z$

By the universal property of subspace topology, we have an induced map $i \circ f$ continuous from $X$ to $Z$, moreover, $i \circ f$ equals to $f$ except for the codomain. So we say $f$ is also continuous from $X$ to $Z$?

Second case $fX \subset Y$, I shrink $Y$ to $fX$, I define a function $g$ such that $i \circ g=f$, still by the universal property of subspace topology, I have $g$ continuous. $g$ equals to $f$ except for the codomain. So we say $f$ is also continuous from $X$ to $fX$?

Comment: Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and let $f:X\to Y$ be a function. Then $f$ is continuous iff whenever $(x_\lambda)$ is a net in $X$ which converges to some $x\in X$, then $(f(x_\lambda))_\lambda$ converges to $f(x)$. This characterization shows that continuity of $f$ only depends on $Y$ by way of the topology it induces on the set $f(X)$. So if $f(X)\subset Y\cap Z$ and $Y,Z$ induce the same topology on $f(X)$, then $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff $f:X\to Z$ is continuous.

Comment: So the answer to your question is yes, but I would like to emphasize the important aspect of your question, which is that you're concerned with the case in which subsets have the subspace topology. It is possible to have a topological space $Y$ with more than one topology. There may be a natural topology on $Y$ and another natural topology on $Z$ in a situation where $Y$ is a subset of $Z$, but the topology on $Y$ that it inherits as a subspace of $Z$ is not the same as the original topology on $Y$.

Comment: @jwhite I find that most people don't really understand/dislike arguments using nets.

Comment: If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous and $V\subseteq f(X)$ is open in $f(X)$, then $V = U\cap f(X)$ where $U$ is open in $Y$. Then $f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$, so the function $f:X\to f(X)$ is continuous. And if $Z$ is any space having $f(X)$ as a subspace, then the composition of $f:X\to f(X)$ with embedding $f(X)\to Z$ is continuous.

Comment: @Jakobian I've found the same thing.